# Importar funcion desde una carpeta a otra en python

Tags: python, importación, modulos

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer pruebas unitarias

Tengo el siguiente directorio

```
calculadora
│   main.py
│   __init__.py
│
├───ecuacion
│       suma.py
│       __init__.py
│
└───tests
        suma_test.py
        __init__.py
```

Dentro del archivo suma.py esta el siguiente codigo

```
def sumar(numero1, numero2):
    return numero1 + numero2
```

Ahora quiero importar dicha funcion al archivo suma_test

He probado 2 formas
La primera es la siguiente con su error:

```
from calculadora.ecuacion import suma

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\calculadora\tests\suma_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from calculadora.ecuacion import suma
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'calculadora'
```

Y esta otra forma con su respectivo error:

```
from ecuacion import suma

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\calculadora\tests\suma_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ecuacion import suma
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ecuacion'
```

Cómo puedo hacer el import? y tambien quiero saber si esta mal que quiera separar las pruebas unitarias en una carpeta distinta de donde tengo el codigo del proyecto, si es una mala practica como puedo organizar las carpetas manteniendo buenas practicas?

Comment: Prueba utilizando: ```from ..ecuacion import suma```.

Comment: Sobre la última pregunta, aunque no existe una única forma de estructurar un proyecto, en general los tests se separan de lo que es en si el paquete. Pero hay quien usa los tests ~en lugar de~ como documentación, incluso se integran en los comentarios (eg: doctest), pero no resulta luego nada fácil de mantener. Te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a este artículo: https://realpython.com/python-application-layouts/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya que has añadido los `__init__.py` en cada carpeta, lo que tienes es un "paquete" (que no es más que una serie de "módulos", organizados en diferentes ficheros .py)

Además, tus sub-carpetas tienen también `__init__.py`, lo que les convierte en sub-paquetes.

Todo esto implica que cuando estén instalados (si llegaras a escribir un instalador para ellos, de modo que `pip install calculadora` copiara todos los ficheros relevantes a la carpeta donde python guarda sus librerías), entonces podrás hacer cosas como `from calculadora.ecuacion import suma`. Pero mientras no estén instalados el paquete `calculadora` no será encontrado por Python a menos que lo intentes importar desde la carpeta padre de `calculadora`

Por tanto, lo siguiente sí funcionará (muestro algunos comandos unix para contexto, para dejar claro en qué carpeta estamos):

```
$ pwd
[...]/calculadora
$ cd ..
$ tree calculadora
calculadora
├── ecuacion
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── suma.py
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── suma_test.py

$ cat calculadora/tests/suma_test.py
from calculadora.ecuacion import suma

def test_suma():
    assert suma.sumar(1,2) == 3

$ pytest calculadora/tests/
============================================ test session starts ============================================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.1, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/abulafia
collected 1 item

calculadora/tests/suma_test.py .                                                                      [100%]

============================================= 1 passed in 0.03s =============================================
```

Como ves, el `from calculadora.ecuacion import suma` ha funcionado y el test ha pasado.

### Una solución mejor

Pero aprovechando que la carpeta `tests` es un **subpaquete** del paquete `calculadora` (porque también tiene su `__init__.py`) entonces puedes hacer uso de los **import relativos**, que consisten en poner un `.` o un `..` delante del nombre del paquete o módulo que quieras importar. Por ejemplo:

```
import .cosa
```

importaría el módulo (o subpaquete) `cosa` que estaría en la misma carpeta que el fichero que está intentando el import.

O bien:

```
import ..otra_cosa
```

importaría el módulo (o subpaquete) `otra_cosa` que estaría en la carpeta inmediatamente superior a la que intenta el import.

Por tanto en tu caso puedes cambiar la primera línea de `suma_test.py` a lo siguiente:

```
from ..ecuacion import suma
```

Esto hace que ese import funcione ya desde cualquier carpeta, con tal de que desde esa carpeta se pueda ejecutar `suma_test.py`. Por tanto ahora puedes ejecutar `pytest` como en el ejemplo anterior, pero también puedes hacerlo directamente dentro de la carpeta `calculadora` e incluso dentro de la carpeta `tests`:

```
$ cd calculadora
$ pytest
platform linux -- Python 3.11.1, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/abulafia/calculadora
collected 1 item

tests/suma_test.py .                                                                                  [100%]

============================================= 1 passed in 0.03s =============================================

$ cd tests
$ pytest
============================================ test session starts ============================================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.1, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/abulafia/calculadora/tests
collected 1 item

suma_test.py .                                                                                        [100%]

============================================= 1 passed in 0.02s =============================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Tendrías que utilizar el módulo `sys` para adjuntar a la ruta `..` y de esa forma poder importar desde la carpeta "padre".

Ejemplo:

```
import sys
 
# Adjuntar la ruta del directorio "padre"
sys.path.append("..")
 
# Importar de la carpeta "hermana" el módulo completo
import ecuacion.suma

# Importar de la carpeta "hermana" una función del módulo suma
from ecuacion.suma import func_suma
```